# Is there an easier way to extract certain bits from a hex value in string format?

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation, c-strings, bitmask

I feel like I'm *way* over-thinking this and that there must be a simpler way.

Let's say I have a string in hexidecimal format, like:

"0x1fffff51"

(Binary: 0001 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101 0001)

Now, depending on some information I have, I need to extract the the first x binary bits, then the next y binary bits, then the remaining 32 - x - y binary bits.

Let's say x = 5, y = 7

So I would want:

x = 10001 = 17

y = 1111010 = 122

z = 0001 1111 1111 1111 1111 = 131071

The way I was thinking of approaching it was:

1. Convert the string into a decimal using strtoul()
2. Create a new mask dynamically using mask = 2^x - 1 (all 1's, length of x number of bits)
   3 Bitwise and MASK and the decimal value (store as X)
3. Create a new mask dynamically using mask = 2^y - 1
4. Shift the decimal number x bits to the right
5. Bitwise and MASK and the decimal value (store as Y)
6. Shift the decimal number y bits to the right, store as Z

I'm almost 100% positive bit shifting works on decimal numbers, so I don't think that'll be a problem.

Comment: Sounds about right.  Code it up, and come back if you have problems getting it working.

Comment: It sound ok, so write your code and if you still have problems with it, you can post the code and we can comment it or point out the errors in the code.

Comment: As long as the variable is an `unsigned` type that's at least 32-bits, your method is fine.

Comment: Don't convert the binary string to decimal, go straight to the internal binary number format.

Comment: this bit map: `(Binary: 0001 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101 0001)` does NOT match the string: `"0x1fffff51"!   However, it would match the hex number: `0x1fffff51`

Comment: Ok. Just thought I might be over-thinking it a little. Been awhile since I've worked with hex in C or done bit shifting/masking stuff. Thanks all!

Comment: this `Create a new mask dynamically using mask = 2^x - 1 (all 1's, length of x number of bits)` is not correct.  As a simple example, 2^2 = 4 = 0x0100, -1 is 0xFF, which is NOT 2 '1' bits

Comment: I think it's right, right? If I need the first 4 bits, I need a 4-bit long mask. 2^4 = 16, 16 - 1 = 15, 15 = 1111

Comment: @TylerShellberg: The only problem I see here is that you're using the words "decimal number" for integers. Integers should be considered as not having any base at all (until they're interpreted as having a base by something like `printf()` - e.g. the `%d` or `%x` specifiers)